# referencing an index value of a character in a pointer string in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Suppose I have something like this

```
int strLen;

printf("Please enter a number: ");
scanf("%d", &strLen);

char *myString;

myString = (char*) malloc(strLen*sizeof(char));
```

then you fill string with something like "Hello World!" but now I want to just print out "World!"  Since my string is just a pointer reference, I can't call it out by indexes ie.

```
for(int i=6;i<strLen;i++)
{
    printf("%s", myString[i]);
}
// THIS IS AN INCORRECT WAY TO DO THIS
```

How could I refer to a specific character or even pass the array onto another function of the program if all I have is the array base pointer? Can I ever get the full functionality as if I declared it as a static array before compile time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1) Allow for the null terminator in your "malloc()":

```
int strLen;
...
char *myString = (char*) malloc(strLen+1);
```

2) The "sizeof(char)" is kind of duplicate redundant.  No harm - but no purpose, either.  So I omitted it.

3) This is wrong:

```
for(int i=6;i<strLen;i++)
{
  printf("%s", myString[i]);
}
```

4) This is better:

```
for(int i=6;i<strLen;i++)
{
  printf("%c", myString[i]);
}
```

Comment: Another answer mentioned the same thing, thanks for giving a little time to a newcomer!

Comment: char does not have to be necessarily 8b though in 99.99999% cases it is. C is likely to be used in 20 years and nobody knows what will size char will be then.

Answer (score 3):

> How could I refer to a specific character or even pass the array onto another function of the program if all I have is the array base pointer?

Several things to remember:

- Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be replaced with ("decay to") an expression of type "pointer to `T`" whose value is the address of the first element of the array;
- In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are identical to `T *a` (IOW, `a` will be declared as a pointer to `T`, not an array of `T` - note that this is *only* true for function parameter declarations);
- The subscript operation `a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a + i)` - start with a base address specified by the pointer expression `a`, offset by `i` elements (***not bytes***), and dereference the result;
- In C, you do not need to cast the result of `malloc` (or `calloc` or `realloc`), since it returns a value of type `void *`, which may be assigned to any other object pointer type.  Adding the cast may suppress a useful diagnostic if you forget to include `stdlib.h` or otherwise don't have a prototype in scope.  Note that this is **not** true for C++ - a cast *is* required there, but if you're writing C++ you should be using `new` instead of `malloc` anyway.

This is a long-winded way of saying that, in many contexts, array expressions and pointer expressions can be treated the same way.  Taking `printf` as an example:

```
int main(void)
{
  char foo[] = "This is a test";
  char *bar = foo;

  printf("%s\n", foo);
  printf("%s\n", &foo[0]);
  printf("%s\n", bar);

  return 0;
}
```

`printf` expects the argument corresponding to `%s` to have type `char *`, or "pointer to `char`", *not* "array of `char`".  The three `printf` calls above are all equivalent.  In the first call, `foo` is an array expression with type "15-element array of `char`".  By the first rule mentioned above, it will be replaced with an expression of type "pointer to `char`" whose value is the address of the first element.  The second and third calls pass the pointer value directly, just using different expressions to accomplish the same effect.

As far as `printf` is concerned, all three expressions yield the same result -- the address of the first element of a sequence of `char` values, terminated by `0`.

What does this mean for your code?  Well, for one thing, you can use the subscript operator on `mystring` as though it were an array type:

```
printf("%s\n", &mystring[6]); // prints "World!"
```

Note that the subscript operator `[]` has higher precedence than the unary `&` operator, so the above is interpreted as `&(mystring[6])` - we subscript into `mystring` and then take the address of the result.

You can pass `mystring` to any function that you would pass an array of `char` to:

```
void foo(char str[]) // identical to char *str
{
  // do something with str
}
...
int main(void)
{
  char str[] = "Hello, World!";
  char *mystr = malloc(strlen(str) + 1); // note no cast
  strcpy(mystr, str);
  foo(str);
  foo(mystr);
  ...
}
```

Again, as far as the function `foo` is concerned, its argument is type `char *`, not array of `char`.  The expression `str` decays to a pointer value, and `mystr` is a pointer value to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the address of the character at a certain array index.

So, try this if you just want to print out 'world!':

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int a, char** b)
{
   int strLen;

   char *myString;

   myString = "hello world!";

   printf("%s", &myString[6]);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ Michael Chinen  ^That will give me element 6 and on, but what if I wanted JUST element 6?

Comment: @JasonM. The way you've been doing it, by indexing, eg. myString[6] will give you the character value at index 6.  &myString[6] gives you a pointer to element 6.  So to print just that char you just have to modify the printf format string: printf("%c", myString[6]);

Comment: Alright, thanks for clearing that up.  It's hard to find these kinds of answers in a text book so this is probably a lot more helpful to me than you think, thanks!